# How can I check the current state of a token I made?

Tags: tokens, logs, database

How can I check what coins have gone where using the standard coin contract? I know how to check the balance of an address, but I'd like to see something like a ledger of all the current coin balances. Optionally I would accept a log of all coin transfers as well (because I can parse this info to build a ledger).

I mostly want to see where/how my coins are moving to ensure a healthy ecosystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [live.ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp/account/f4eced2f682ce333f96f2d8966c613ded8fc95dd) to see all of the accounts that have your token. That link goes to the MistCoin contract. If you click the mapping in the "storage" section, you can see the mapping from addresses to balances.

[image]

If you want to be able to check balances easier, try using an [iterable mapping](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol) in your contract to store the balances.